# Cancellation fee on failed booking

Tags: bookings, hotels, cancellations, booking.com

What happens if:

1. I book a non-refundable room on booking.com;
2. Credit card is invalid;
3. The bank said the transaction failed;
4. I cancel the booking.

What about the cancellation fee?

Comment: If the booking actually failed, there is no booking to cancel.  If the booking actually succeeded, you owe the money, whether the credit card is valid or not, because you have a valid non-cancellable booking.  If you don't want cancellation penalties, don't book non-refundable bookings.

Answer (score 1):

The card was declined before the booking was made. Therefore no contact existed, so there never was a booking to cancel. So there cannot be a cancellation fee.

This question has very little to do with travel and might be better posted in Money .

Comment: I would still contact the booking site and/or the hotel to make sure the booking was not made. Easier to explain the problem before the planned stay than to fight off a 'no show up' claim.

Comment: This is the reply from the hotel:        Concerning your request, we confirm you that the reservations were cancelled it by the person that book it.

 

We couldn’t charge it any fee cause the credit card  is not valid.

 

We invite you to contact Booking also in order to be sure that no fee is charged

Comment: @vitaj could you post this as an answer?